# Deceive the JVM about the number of available cores (on linux)

Tags: linux, jvm, cpu-cores

In some purpose it is needed to make `JVM` think about it runs on machine with `N`cores on board instead of real number of cores (e.g. `4` cores instead of `16`).

`JVM` runs under some Linux build, based on Mandriva/Red Hat Linux core.

This question is borderline case because I expect various solutions of this problem. This is not pure linux-administration question, and it isn't pure programmer's question.

So... any ideas?

Comment: `man cpuset` should help.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It would be nice, and I think helpful, if you could provide some live example how to do this with running `java` jar

Comment: Should the JVM only be scheduled to 4 cores? Or should the JVM think there are only 4 cores, so that it starts only 4 threads for parallel execution? Does it have to be a process-specific setting, or is a (temporary) system-wide change also okay?

Comment: @nosid `JVM` should think and see only `4` cores instead of their real   number

Comment: If cgroups is available on Mandriva use it. With cgroups, you can allocate resources per process group. In your case you wanted only 4 cpus allocated to your JVM. Here's a wiki about cgroups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following Java program prints the number of processors as seen by the Java VM:

```
public class AvailableProcessors {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }
}
```

If I execute this program on my home computer, it prints `4`, which is the actual number of cores (including hyper threading). Now let's trick the Java VM into believing there are only two processors:

```
$ echo '0-1' > /tmp/online
$ mount --bind /tmp/online /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
```

If I run the above program again, it prints `2` instead of `4`.

This trick affects all processes on your system. However, it's possible to restrict the effect only to certain processes. Each process on Linux can have its own namespace of mount points. See for example the section [Pre-process namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html#NOTES) in the man page of *mount(2)*. You can for example use [lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc.html) to start new processes with their own *mount namespace*.

Comment: Well, this is hard hack. Ok, let it be :)

Comment: I found this to be a better solution:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-rhel-centos-redhat-suse-hotplug-cpu/

Answer (score 11):

In order to make `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` return whatever you want, you can override `JVM_ActiveProcessorCount` function using `LD_PRELOAD` trick. Here is a tiny program to do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int JVM_ActiveProcessorCount(void) {
    char* val = getenv("_NUM_CPUS");
    return val != NULL ? atoi(val) : sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
}
```

First, make a shared library of this:

```
gcc -O3 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libnumcpus.so -o libnumcpus.so numcpus.c
```

Then run Java as follows:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libnumcpus.so _NUM_CPUS=2 java AvailableProcessors
```

Comment: Note that JVM also uses `sysconf()` to calculate the number of compiler and GC thread. However you can set the number of JVM threads explicitly using `-XX:CICompilerCount=n -XX:ConcGCThreads=m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=m`

Comment: In Java 9 it will actually inspect the cpuset on Linux.

Comment: Also @apangin pointed to [JDK-8u-121](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6515172) that fixes this problem.