# Limit number of active threads/cores a JVM can use

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm

I have a piece of code in Scala (using Java execution context) that spawns many threads.
Also I have an 8 core CPU.

When the process runs it uses up all the juice my computer has and I cannot do anything else.

Is there a way I can limit the JVM to only 7 cores, or the Java execution context to 7 active threads?

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741859/deceive-the-jvm-about-the-number-of-available-cores-on-linux

Answer (score -1):

Use fixed thread pool and set the fixed pool size to 7

Comment: It would be nice with an example of how to do this.