# How to interpret the profile results in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

I was profiling the CPU usage of a sample java app with Netbeans 8.1:

Profile of the cpu time for classes:
[image]

I've read the Profiler documentation and [I found the difference between CPU and Wall Clock time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335920/111110), and that ["Total Time" and "CPU Time" are equal to "wall clock time" and "CPU time"](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerMethods).
But in the documentation I couldn't find info about the percentage in grey by the side of the usage time in the Total Time and CPU Time columns: Is this the percentage of CPU usage per core?

In this image:
Telemetry:
[image]

CPU usage never hits 100%. [Does Netbeans profiler measures CPU usage like VisualVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952512/111110)